# Can I substitute ${} variable for value of a string literal while running a custom ESLint rule?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Currently I have a basic check on validity of a template literal which uses external variables, minimal example of such a literal:

```js
const query = `

action {
...variable
}

${variable}`
```

This is ONLY a minimal example, the exact check I make is also not important, the point is - there is something I'd like to check for inside the variable's definition as well in my rule, so I was wondering whether I can substitute the ${variable} for its actual value on my custom ESLint rule run. If not, I'll resort to a code refactor and simple counting approach, but I would like to know if there is a way for my custom ESLint rule to "see" what is inside.

Tried to use a more basic approach with counting distinct names for variables, though in some places in the code there might be a mismatch so it won't cover all the cases I'd like the rule to check. Also went through code of some ESLint rules and docs but did not see a parallel case to the one I have now, substituting variables for their values. Might be that I just could not find them though.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. You cannot substitute `variable` by its value without executing the code. However, for certain subsets of programs (e.g. where `variable` is defined as a `const`, initialised to another string), you can do some static analysis in your rule. The [graphql eslint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@graphql-eslint/eslint-plugin) does something like this.